# pandas version of numpy's ones_like

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

consider `pd.Series` `s`

```
s = pd.Series([.4, .5, .6], list('abc'))
s

a    0.4
b    0.5
c    0.6
dtype: float64
```

I've done this before to get a series of ones

```
pd.Series(np.ones_like(s.values), s.index, name=s.name)

a    1.0
b    1.0
c    1.0
dtype: float64
```

What is a better way?

Comment: Is it just for series with floats? Or do you want to deal with e.g. a dataframe with integers?

Comment: I've dealing with floats.  Integers are interesting, but i have lots of np.nan

Comment: This seems to be slightly faster: `pd.Series(np.ones(s.shape), s.index, name=s.name)`

Comment: It also generalizes to dataframes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make use of [`Series.copy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.copy.html) and by disabling it's `deep` paramater to speed up the entire process. Later, use [`ndarray.fill`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.fill.html) to fill all those values present in the series with 1.

Let's take a `DF` to illustrate whose values are half filled with `Nan`:

```
np.random.seed(42)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10**6,), columns=['A'])
# Populate values with Nans
df.loc[df.sample(frac=0.5).index] = np.NaN

df.shape
# (1000000, 1)

def fill_ones_with_modify():
    ser = df['A'].copy(deep=False)     # use copy() → without modifying the original DF
    ser.values.fill(1)
    return ser

%timeit fill_ones_with_modify()
1000 loops, best of 3: 837 µs per loop
```

***Note:*** This operates `inplace` on the series and so the the resulting series of the `DF` would be altered as well (filled with 1's).

---

Another way is to access the series as a single column of the `DF` and flatten it after copying to return a series object instead. This however, takes much more time as the underlying data and the indices are copied. *Upside* - Doesn't modify the referenced series object.

```
def fill_ones_without_modify():
    ser = df[['A']].copy(deep=False).squeeze()
    ser.values.fill(1)
    return ser

%timeit fill_ones_without_modify()
100 loops, best of 3: 6.4 ms per loop
```

Comment: I had a ton of answers off the top of my head `s_ = s.copy(); s_.loc[:] = 1` or `s.mul(0).add(1).fillna(1)` or what @Tuan333 posted.  This is a thoughtful and really useful method.  I appreciated it!  Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome! Yeah, you learn by trying different approaches and by gauging it's pros and cons in the meantime. And also, it's nice to see you attacking `pandas` questions and giving such marvelous answers. keep it up!

Comment: @piRSquared I believe there is a huge problem with that answer; it modifies the original dataframe. Check `df.head()` after calling `fill_ones`, it is... filled with ones.

Comment: @IanS nice catch! Nickil, I'm removing the answer check for now.

Comment: @piRSquared, Fixed. But a tad slower when using a `deepcopy` compared to a series construction with `np.ones_like`.

Answer (score 2):

A way (not sure if it's the best way) is to make use of element-wise division and `fillna` method. Should work even if there are `0` and `np.nan` in the original `Series`. E.g.

```
>>> a = pandas.Series(np.array([0,np.nan,2,3,4]), list('abcde'))
>>> a
a    0.0
b    NaN
c    2.0
d    3.0
e    4.0
dtype: float64
>>> (a/a).fillna(1)
a    1.0
b    1.0
c    1.0
d    1.0
e    1.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2):

This question was just upvoted on 2019-02-21 ~2.5 years after I asked it.  I realize that I'd never actually use the thing I proposed and I'd simply do

```
pd.Series(1, s.index, name=s.name)
```

In this case, Pandas will broadcast `1` across the index for us.  I like this because it is far and away simpler.  However, it is not quicker

Suppose I had

```
s = pd.Series(5, range(int(1e6)))
```

Then the timings are

```
%timeit pd.Series(1, s.index, name=s.name)
%timeit pd.Series(np.ones(s.shape), s.index, name=s.name)
%timeit fill_ones_with_modify(s)
%timeit s.div(s).fillna(1)

413 µs ± 2.03 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
375 µs ± 2.04 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
369 µs ± 975 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
3.47 ms ± 12.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

I'm not interested in micro optimizations at that level.  IMO 413 is close enough to 369.  I'll take simplicity in this situation.